# Backup data base in oracle 12C

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, rman

We have 12c database. we had create a pdb. Now i want to take a backup through
RMAN. Could you please share the steps to configure this backup.

I know to configure backup in 11g..For 12c Please share the steps.

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Backing Up PDBs with RMAN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/bradv/backing-up-database.html#GUID-655DC5F5-FF8D-4A73-B67D-F5AAE20CA382)

> To back up one or more PDBs while connected to the root:
>
> 1. Start RMAN and connect to the root as a common user with the SYSBACKUP
>      or SYSDBA privilege as described in Connecting as Target to the Root.
> 2. Issue a `BACKUP PLUGGABLE DATABASE` command at the RMAN prompt.
>
> The following example backs up the PDBs sales and hr:
>
> `BACKUP PLUGGABLE DATABASE sales, hr;`
>
> To back up one PDB while connected to the PDB:
>
> 1. Start RMAN and connect to the PDB as a local user with the SYSBACKUP
>      or SYSDBA privilege as described in Connecting as Target to a PDB.
> 2. Issue a BACKUP DATABASE command at the RMAN prompt.
>
> `BACKUP DATABASE;`

Comment: We only need to backup pdb? @Balazs Papp

Comment: @RahmanGurbaz No, but that is what you asked for. The whole CDB should be backed up.

Comment: Ok thank you for clarification... @Balazs Papp